# Forcing plot to have "0" in the middle and scale equally for + and - values, in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following plot:

```
rm(list=ls())
dat <- data.frame(
  FunctionClass = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",     "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"), levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z")),
  legend = c("A: RNA processing and modification", "B: Chromatin structure and dynamics", "C: Energy production and conversion", "D: Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning", "E: Amino acid transport and metabolism", "F: Nucleotide transport and metabolism", "G: Carbohydrate transport and metabolism", "H: Coenzyme transport and metabolism", "I: Lipid transport and metabolism", "J: Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis", "K: Transcription", "L: Replication, recombination and repair", "M: Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", "N: Cell motility", "O: Posttranslational modification, protein turnover, chaperones", "P: Inorganic ion transport and metabolism", "Q: Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport and catabolism", "R: General function prediction only", "S: Function unknown", "T: Signal transduction mechanisms", "U: Intracellular trafficking, secretion, and vesicular transport", "V: Defense mechanisms", "W: Extracellular structures", "X: Mobilome: prophages, transposons", "Z: Cytoskeleton"),
  Differential_Abundance=c(1.943765281,0,1.550400926,-1.48041182,1.454818661,1.197623814,1.672007118,-1.461162549,1.445611787,1.143529214,1.593145314,1.394636154,1.374263719,1.915024746,1.59584055,1.609526035,1.833848642,1.510431257,2.011279296,1.685412835,1.804628351,1.526193538,2.150023889,4.141168637,0)
)
dat2 <- data.frame(
  FunctionClass = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",     "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"), levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z")),
  legend = c("A: RNA processing and modification", "B: Chromatin structure and dynamics", "C: Energy production and conversion", "D: Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning", "E: Amino acid transport and metabolism", "F: Nucleotide transport and metabolism", "G: Carbohydrate transport and metabolism", "H: Coenzyme transport and metabolism", "I: Lipid transport and metabolism", "J: Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis", "K: Transcription", "L: Replication, recombination and repair", "M: Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", "N: Cell motility", "O: Posttranslational modification, protein turnover, chaperones", "P: Inorganic ion transport and metabolism", "Q: Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport and catabolism", "R: General function prediction only", "S: Function unknown", "T: Signal transduction mechanisms", "U: Intracellular trafficking, secretion, and vesicular transport", "V: Defense mechanisms", "W: Extracellular structures", "X: Mobilome: prophages, transposons", "Z: Cytoskeleton"),
  Differential_Abundance=c(0.274193548,0,0.636797142,0.760586841,0.697258963,0.762676492,0.635342063,0.663631422,0.645097978,0.779545231,0.640177994,0.727535909,0.689333748,0.735359361,0.640193282,0.635588068,0.550945647,0.674768806,0.474391713,0.625893905,0.6735326,0.673786336,0.373358349,0.788830716,0)
)
dat3 <- data.frame(
  FunctionClass = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",     "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"), levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z")),
  legend = c("A: RNA processing and modification", "B: Chromatin structure and dynamics", "C: Energy production and conversion", "D: Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning", "E: Amino acid transport and metabolism", "F: Nucleotide transport and metabolism", "G: Carbohydrate transport and metabolism", "H: Coenzyme transport and metabolism", "I: Lipid transport and metabolism", "J: Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis", "K: Transcription", "L: Replication, recombination and repair", "M: Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", "N: Cell motility", "O: Posttranslational modification, protein turnover, chaperones", "P: Inorganic ion transport and metabolism", "Q: Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport and catabolism", "R: General function prediction only", "S: Function unknown", "T: Signal transduction mechanisms", "U: Intracellular trafficking, secretion, and vesicular transport", "V: Defense mechanisms", "W: Extracellular structures", "X: Mobilome: prophages, transposons", "Z: Cytoskeleton"),
  Differential_Abundance=c(9,0,1.0799866,1.091797259,-1.130650855,1.117397043,1.154323063,1.120285744,1.109707602,1.03124137,1.082538796,1.144749691,1.132706793,1.20291278,1.087030717,1.195695364,1.128030751,1.114057756,1.049278846,1.11277533,1.0745219,1.183166385,1.424403183,1.344569288,0)
)
dat4 <- data.frame(
  FunctionClass = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",     "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"), levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z")),
  legend = c("A: RNA processing and modification", "B: Chromatin structure and dynamics", "C: Energy production and conversion", "D: Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning", "E: Amino acid transport and metabolism", "F: Nucleotide transport and metabolism", "G: Carbohydrate transport and metabolism", "H: Coenzyme transport and metabolism", "I: Lipid transport and metabolism", "J: Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis", "K: Transcription", "L: Replication, recombination and repair", "M: Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", "N: Cell motility", "O: Posttranslational modification, protein turnover, chaperones", "P: Inorganic ion transport and metabolism", "Q: Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport and catabolism", "R: General function prediction only", "S: Function unknown", "T: Signal transduction mechanisms", "U: Intracellular trafficking, secretion, and vesicular transport", "V: Defense mechanisms", "W: Extracellular structures", "X: Mobilome: prophages, transposons", "Z: Cytoskeleton"),
  Differential_Abundance=c(0.96969697,0,-1.231767223,1.008973531,1.024348498,1.029287918,0.976474705,1.148176473,1.046733282,1.180224765,1.078631515,0.961294348,1.059904036,1.147982063,1.133098611,0.985634747,0.899535669,1.013583458,0.779766123,0.990262902,1.048154657,1.068109275,0.998245614,1.033285886,0)
)


dataug <- rbind(transform(dat, label="Timepoint 1"), # first frame
                transform(dat2, label="Timepoint 2"), # second frame
                transform(dat3, label="Timepoint 3"), # ...
                transform(dat4, label="Timepoint 4"))
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=dataug, aes(x=FunctionClass, y=Differential_Abundance, fill=legend))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="seashell")
p + guides (fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dat$FunctionClass))) +
  xlab("COG Class") +
  ylab("Differential Abundance (Treated/Untreated)") +
  facet_wrap(~ label) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Whenever i get values that are too high, or too low, the plot shifts its center. What I need, is for the plot to have "0" in the middle of the plot and then scale equally for positive and negative values. So in this case, the plot goes up to 7,5 for positve values. I need it to also go to -7,5 for negative values, so the plot is "centered".

Is this possible somehow??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scale_y_continuous` and the argument `limits` to set limits of the y axis and be sure they will be kept between -7.5 and 7.5:

```r
ggplot(data = dataug, aes(x = FunctionClass, y=Differential_Abundance, fill=legend))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour = "seashell")+
  guides (fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-7.5,7.5), breaks = seq(-7.5,7.5,by = 2.5))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dat$FunctionClass))) +
  facet_wrap(.~label) +
  labs(x = "COG Class" , y = "Differential Abundance (Treated/Untreated)")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]